# How to assign tags to every file and then filter by these tags in GCS?

Tags: node.js, database, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, filesystems

I'm using *Google Cloud Storage* to store 100-150 files, mostly pictures (<30MG) and a few videos (<100MG). The number of files should remain around what it is right now, so I'm not that worried about scalability. All of the files are in the same storage bucket.

---

My goal is to assign **at least one *tag*** (string) and **a number of upvotes** (integer) to every file.

I want to be able to:

1. Filter all of the files by their tag(s) and only retrieve the ones with said tag.

   *A file **may** have several tags, such as "halloween", "christmas" and "easter", and must be retrieved if **any** of its tags is specified*
2. Then, sort the filtered files by their number of upvotes (descending order).

   In other words, the end goal is to get a *sorted* list of the the *filtered* files' URLs (to show on a website similar to *[Imgur](https://imgur.com/)*).

---

Right now, I've come up with two (potential) ways to do that:

1. **CUSTOM METADATA KEY**

   > When adding a file to the bucket, add **a custom key for the tags** and **another** **one for the number of upvotes**. Then, when I want to retrieve all files with the "halloween" tag, I can:
   >
   > 1. Loop through every file and get its metadata ([doc](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/viewing-editing-metadata#client-libraries))
   > 2. Filter and sort all of the files based on the metadata's keys
   > 3. Get the URL of each file
   >
   > Seems like this could cause some performance issues, but would be an easy structure.
2. **INDEX FILE**

> Create an index file (in JSON). When adding a file to the bucket, also add the file's info to the index...
>
> Eg:
>
> ```
> {
>    "files": [
>       {
>          "filename": "file1",
>          "path": "/path/to/file1",
>          "tags": ["tag1", "tag2", "tag3"],
>          "upvotes": 10
>       },
>       {
>          "filename": "file2",
>          "path": "/path/to/file2",
>          "tags": ["tag4", "tag5"],
>          "upvotes": 5
>       },
>       {
>          "filename": "file3",
>          "path": "/path/to/file3",
>          "tags": [],
>          "upvotes": 0
>       }
>    ]
> }
> ```
>
> Then, when I want to retrieve all files with the "halloween" tag, I can:
>
> 1. Parse the json file to get all the files with the "halloween" tag
> 2. Sort based on the upvotes key
> 3. Get the URL of each file
>
> I *think* this would be better performance-wise? I'm leaning towards this one right now...
>
> But I don't love the idea of having an external index file.

1. Are both methods possible to implement? Is there a better way to do this?

   *Disclaimer: I'm pretty new to databases (especially GCS).*
2. If not, which one would have the best performance? Doesn't need to be blazing fast, it's a school project.

Thanks!

Comment: As you said, you are new to database because GCS is not a database, it's a blob storage space. It store blob, no more. You can add metadata but you can't really query on it. You can read them, but that's all. The best solution is to have a database, such as Firestore that is serverless, with a cool free tier and designed for that usage.

Comment: Thanks for you answer, I’ll definitely look more into Firestore as it seems to better suit my needs. If I chose Firestore, do you have any idea which option (#1 or #2 from my post) would have the best performance (generally-speaking). Obviously, I’ll try to run some (other) tests on my own to see which option has the lowest latency before rendering the picture/video on my website.

Comment: The second one, but you haven't an index file. You have 1 document in Firestore for each object in Cloud Storage. Then you can query Firestore to get the same tags or stuff like that. Be careful, Firestore is weak in term of query. You can't perform aggregation, max or sum. But, if you have only a few number of file, you can perform that computation in memory in your application after getting all the document from Firestore.